# Can not configure a Starlette .env file

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I'm trying to set up the .env file for my project. But it seems incorrect.

I store the .env file in the same folder as the config.py file as below.

```
|__run.py
|___|myproject
    |__config.py
    |__.env
```

Code in my config.py file:

```
from starlette.config import Config
from starlette.datastructures import Secret, CommaSeparatedStrings
config = Config(".env")
BACKHUG_JWT_AES_KEY = config('BACKHUG_JWT_AES_KEY', default=None)

print(type(BACKHUG_JWT_AES_KEY))
print(BACKHUG_JWT_AES_KEY)
```

Data in the .env file:

```
BACKHUG_JWT_AES_KEY="SAMPLE_AES_KEY"
```

But the result I got was:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
None
```

I don't know why it got the *None* object. How can I fix it?

I run my project from a *run.py* file.

Code in the *run.py* file:

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("myproject.main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8888, reload=True)
```

Comment: What you have got if you put `print(open(".env").read())` on the top of `config.py` ?

Comment: Hello @ArakkalAbu,
When I run the config.py file, I can get data from .env file. But when I run the server using run.py file. I can not get data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way!

Use **FastAPI** and **Pydantic** for this. Pydantic provides a great `BaseSettings` class. Also, we have great documentation for [**settings and environment variables**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/).

Create a `Settings` class by inheriting from **Pydantic**'s `BaseSettings`:

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    backhug_jwt_access_key: str

    class Config:
        env_file = "myproject/.env"
```

This *Settings* class automatically reads the variables from the `.env` file. Then from your main file you can use it like this:

```py
from . import config
from functools import lru_cache

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@lru_cache()
def get_settings():
    return config.Settings()


@app.get("/info")
async def info(settings: config.Settings = Depends(get_settings)):
    return {"jwt_key": settings.backhug_jwt_access_key}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes in the value and try again:

env file:

```
BACKHUG_JWT_AES_KEY=SAMPLE_AES_KEY
```

Comment: I tried before. But it still does not work.

Comment: what do you get when you `print(config)`

Comment: When I run the config.py file, I can get data from .env file. But when I run the server using run.py file. I can not get data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with the [current working directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html). I can suggest two ways.

- Move the `.env` file to one directory with the `run.py` file

*Or*

- Change the path `config = Config("myproject/.env")`